# How do i create and train tensorflow model with audio inputs?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, audio-processing

I've audio files say "left.wav", "right.wav" and so forth, I want to create a model which takes audio as input and output label "left" or "right" etc.

**Question**

How do I feed my raw audio to my neural network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`scipy.io.wavfile.read()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) function will return the sample rate and the whole audio in a numpy array.

You can then feed that to your network.

```
import scipy
rate, numpy_audio = scipy.io.wavfile.read( "left.wav" )
```

If you want to do speech recognition, check out [DeepSpeech](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech), it's a large project, but you can probably get some good ideas there.

For a simpler intro, Tensorflow has a [Simple Audio Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition) tutorial.

To generate audio, you might want to consider WaveNet - [this is one particular implementation](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet).

Comment: That's it?Nothing more?

Comment: Is it too easy? :)

Comment: Are you trying to do speech recognition?

Comment: Added some links for you in my answer

Comment: hi, Thankyou so much. Yes, I'm just trying to create a basic speech recognition model using tensorflow. :)